# Symfony 3.4 Use view inside my bundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I've some trouble for the configuration of a new repository using Symfony 3.4. I've used the symfony command for create him with last LTS (3.4) and I add a new Bundle using command too. My new Bundle is up and work well but I can't use view stored inside this bundle.

I show you the structure of my Bundle :

[image: structure]

I want to use this index.html.twig in my controller like this :

```
<?php

namespace Lister\ListerBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lister")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('ListerListerBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

But when I try to render it I've this error.

> Unable to find template "ListerListerBundle:Default:index.html.twig" (looked into: /home/emendiel/Data/Code/Perso/WebLister/app/Resources/views, /home/emendiel/Data/Code/Perso/WebLister/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form).

I understand what that say, my folder is not where symfony search my view but I don't found how I can said to Symfony go in "ListerBundle/Ressources/views"

In my oldest project that was work without other configuration.

**Info:** I use my bundle as reusable bundle.

Regards,

**PS:** This is my autoload part in composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
```

**PSS:** My AppKernel :

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = [
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        new Lister\ListerBundle\ListerListerBundle(),
    ];
...
```

**And Again:** Here My dependencyInjection

[image]

And the content of files :

Configuration.php

```
<?php

namespace Lister\ListerBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

/**
 * This is the class that validates and merges configuration from your app/config files.
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html}
 */
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('lister_lister');

        // Here you should define the parameters that are allowed to
        // configure your bundle. See the documentation linked above for
        // more information on that topic.

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

ListerListerExtension.php

```
<?php

namespace Lister\ListerBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration.
 *
 * @link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html
 */
class ListerListerExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

**Solution:** from @Cerad

@ListerLister/Default/index.html.twig

Original response from @Cerad

> For some reason, S3.4 no longer likes the Bundle:Dir:name approach to specifying twig paths and the generate:bundle command has not yet been updated. Not sure if it is a bug or feature. The @ListerLister/Default/index.html.twig path suggested above should work. Try bin/console debug:twig to see your twig namespaces paths. – Cerad

Comment: The right template name should be `ListerBundle:Default:index.html.twig` (without vendor prefix) or use the Twig convention `@Lister/Default/index.html.twig` (recommended).

Comment: Thank you for your response.

In first case I've the same error and with de second case I've this : There are no registered paths for namespace "Lister"

Comment: Have you added this bundle to the kernel `getBundles()`?

Comment: I've add my Appkernel in the original post in PSS section. And so yes I have it. My annotation route is knowed by symfony. Symfony just don't search my view in bundle Resources/views

Comment: i guess you already clear your cache ?

Comment: @MatMouth Yes I do :/ Multiple time dev and prod. I work with app_dev

Comment: Can you post the content of your depencyInjection files ?

Comment: Nevermind, the problem should not be there

Comment: For some reason, S3.4 no longer likes the Bundle:Dir:name approach to specifying twig paths and the generate:bundle command has not yet been updated.  Not sure if it is a bug or feature.  The @ListerLister/Default/index.html.twig path suggested above should work.  Try bin/console debug:twig to see your twig namespaces paths.

Comment: @MatMouth I add the dependencyInjection files

Comment: @Cerad Thank you so much your syntax work.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The basic problem appears to be that in S3.4, twig template paths such as 'ListerListerBundle:Default:index.html.twig' are no longer supported.

Replace the path in the controller with:

```
'@ListerLister/Default/index.html.twig'
```

And all should be well.  If you are ever not sure what the actual namespace prefix is then run:

```
bin/console debug:twig
```

to list them.

S3.3 still works fine so this is something that changed in 3.4.  Supposed to be using the namespaced format anyways so this is not a big deal.

I did file an issue about this on github: https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/issues/587

We shall see what the maintainers have to say.

Update:  The great and powerful Fabpot himself replied to my issue.  If you want to keep using the 'ListerListerBundle:Default:index.html.twig' format for templates then edit your app/config/config.yml file:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
```

You should only do this if you have legacy code which still uses the old format.  Use twig namespaces for all new code.

Comment: I am using 3.4 , its working for me with out adding engines: ['twig'] in config.yml.
The only problem for me was with respect to twig namespace. As it can be found from bin/console debug:twig

Answer (score 0):

#config/config.yml

#after router add like

router:
resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
strict_requirements: ~
templating:
engines: [twig]