# After upgrading Symfony from 3.2 to 3.4 i get the error 'There are no registered paths for namespace "FooBar"

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Does somebody knows why Symfony 3.4 cant find Templates anymore? After upgrading to Symfony from 3.2 to 3.4 i moved all templates in the app/Resources/views folder and now i get the error 'There are no registered paths for namespace "FooBar"'. I was searching the net for solutions but couldn't find any. In which directories is Symfony 3.4 looking to find templates? I also have annotated my controllers with @Template without parameters. What should i do to solve the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832977/symfony-3-4-use-view-inside-my-bundle/47835716#47835716

Comment: Thx Cerad for your fast answer, it helped a lot. After giving the Template annotation the right path to the template in app/Resources/views everything worked fine. I just thought that after updating Symfony and moving all my templates out of the bundles into the app/Resources/views, like they recommanded, Symfony would find the Templates on its own... i was obviously mistaken!

Comment: Glad you got it working.  And don't worry, it changes again in S4.