# Unable to find template Bundle:Default:index.html.twig

Tags: symfony

I'm having some trouble runnning Symfony. In fact, it can't find the default twig template. I didn't touch the code at all, juste generated my bundle and trying to access /web/app_dev.php.

My template is in

```
/src/OC/PlatformBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig.
```

Symfony looked into these locations, but not where my template actually is.

```
/app/Resources/views
/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form
```

And the DefaultController.php indexAction() looks ok :

```
public function indexAction(){
    return $this->render("OCPlatform:Default:index.html.twig");
}
```

If any of you have ever faced this kind of issue or have any idea where the problem comes from, I thank you in advance for your help.

Arthur

Comment: Assuming you are using S3.4 or 4.0 then probably a dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832977/symfony-3-4-use-view-inside-my-bundle/47835716#47835716

Answer (score 2):

I've same problem and i resolve it with this route :

```js
public function indexAction(){
    return $this->render("@OCPlatform/Default/index.html.twig");
}
```

Edit ":" with "/" and it work. 
Maybe can help other developper

Comment: Add an other information. Don't write "bundle". Exemple : 
Use that.
`return $this->render("@OCPlatform/Default/index.html.twig");`

And no :
`return $this->render("@OCPlatformBundle/Default/index.html.twig");`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using the 'OCPlatform:Default:index.html.twig' format for templates then edit your app/config/config.yml file:

```
#app/config/config.yml
framework:
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
```

This fixed my problem. You can check this link 
[Symfony 3.4 Use view inside my bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832977/symfony-3-4-use-view-inside-my-bundle?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

[Following the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating.html#template-naming-and-locations)(Symfony >=3.4) you should write the path to the template in the controller like this:

```
public function indexAction(){
    return $this->render("@OCPlatform:Default:index.html.twig");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
return $this->render('@HomeBundle/Default/index.html.twig');
```

Hope it hope :)

Answer (score 0):

Referencing Templates in a Bundle¶

If you need to refer to a template that lives in a bundle, Symfony uses the 
Twig namespaced syntax (@BundleName/directory/filename.html.twig). 
This allows for several types of templates, each which lives in a specific location:

```
@AcmeBlog/Blog/index.html.twig: <br>This syntax is used to specify a template for a specific page. The three parts of the string, each separated by a slash (/), mean the following:<br>
    @AcmeBlog: is the bundle name without the Bundle suffix. This template lives in the AcmeBlogBundle (e.g. src/Acme/BlogBundle);<br>
    Blog: (directory) indicates that the template lives inside the Blog subdirectory of Resources/views/;<br>
    index.html.twig: (filename) the actual name of the file is index.html.twig.
```

Answer (score 0):

In symfony 4 use this :

```
    return $this->render("@Platform/Default/index.html.twig");
```