# Unable to find template

Tags: php, symfony

İ am new to Symfony. I have a problem. I created a new bundle. I made necessary settings. But I get the following error.

I want to open index.html.twig under BlogBundle/Defaults.

```
Unable to find template "BlogBundle:Default:index.html.twig" (looked into: C:\xampp\htdocs\deneme\app/Resources/views, C:\xampp\htdocs\deneme\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig/Resources/views/Form).
```

DefaultController:

```
<?php

namespace BlogBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('BlogBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

---

```
routing:

    blog:
    resource: "@BlogBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

composer:

```
"name": "user/my_project",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
        "BlogBundle\\": "src/BlogBundle"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\deneme\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig/Resources/views/Form has two different types of slashes

Comment: The bundle:dir:name format has pretty much gone away.  It is possible to still use it with the correct configuration but it is recommended to use twig namespaces so: '@BlogBundle\Default\index.html.twig' should work.  You can use "bin/console debug:twig" to see where the BlogBundle twig namespace is mapped to.

Comment: Basically a dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832977/symfony-3-4-use-view-inside-my-bundle/47835716#47835716

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony 3.4 Use view inside my bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832977/symfony-3-4-use-view-inside-my-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

you need to have an index.html.twig file under one of the followings trees:

- app/resources/views/your_controller_name(Default)/index.html.twig 
  or
- src/your_bundle/resources/views/your_controller_name(Default)/index.html.twig