# Twig form theme and DependencyInjection

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to separate my Symfony bundles.
I have created `SymfonyFormFontAwesomeBundle` and *ExtensionClass* in `DependencyInjection` repertory :

`SymfonyFormFontAwesomeExtension` :

```
class SymfonyFormFontAwesomeExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
            $container,
            new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
        );
        $loader->load('services.yaml');

        $this->loadTwigTheme($container);
    }

    private function loadTwigTheme(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->hasParameter('twig.form.resources')) {
            return;
        }

        $container->setParameter('twig.form.resources', array_merge(
            [
                'SymfonyFormFontAwesomeBundle::theme.html.twig'
            ],
            $container->getParameter('twig.form.resources')
        ));
    }
}
```

But Symfony search theme in my projet (not in my bundle) :

> Unable to find template "SymfonyFormFontAwesomeBundle::theme.html.twig" (looked into: /var/www/symfony/Project/templates, /var/www/symfony/Project/templates, /var/www/symfony/Project/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form).

I want to load the file "theme.html.twig" that is in my bundle.

Can you help me ? :)

Comment: Do you load the bundle in your `AppKernel.php` and have you cleared your cache after adding it?

Comment: Yes, and services.yaml of my bundle is well loaded :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832977/symfony-3-4-use-view-inside-my-bundle/47835716#47835716

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are using Symfony4, while the code you used looks like Symfony 2 code. Since Symfony 3(.2?) the Templating component is not used anymore by Twig, so there may be changes.

I would suggest you 2 modifications:

- instead of setting `twig.form.resources`, use a parameter for the config option `twig.form_themes`, parameter you will be able to easily modify from your bundle extension
- use the `@SymfonyFormFontAwesome::theme.html.twig` syntax, otherwise SF4 will look inside `templates/`

Comment: Thanks ! my mistake is to have added "Bundle" term : "SymfonyFormFontAwesomeBundle::theme.html.twig" :)