# Unable to find template in Bundle

Tags: symfony

I am using `Symfony 3.4.4` and getting Twig_Error_Loader:

```
Unable to find template "MyBundle:Default:index.html.twig" (looked into: /Users/nemanja/sites/SimfoniAplikacija/app/Resources/views, /Users/nemanja/sites/SimfoniAplikacija/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form).
```

This is my default controller in MyBundle/Controller

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/my", name="mypage")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

And my index file is where it says: `MyBundle/Default/index.html.twig`

I tried to change return `$this->render('MyBundle:Default:index.html.twig');`
 to  `return $this->render('MyBundle/Default/index.html.twig');`
But I still get the same error. It can't find index template.

Comment: Missing the @ symbol which idicates a twig namespace. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832977/symfony-3-4-use-view-inside-my-bundle/47835716#47835716

Comment: When I do that, I get: There are no registered paths for namespace "MyBundle"....But I found the namespace with bin/console debug:twig command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I tried to add `@` symbol in front of bundle name:

```
return $this->render('@MyBundle/Default/index.html.twig');
```

But than I get an error:

```
There are no registered paths for namespace "MyBundle".
```

To find out the namespace, I run:

```
bin/console debug:twig
```

This listed

```
...

 @My             - src/MyBundle/Resources/views                                                 
 @!My            - src/MyBundle/Resources/views   

...
```

And than I added in my controller:

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/my", name="mypage")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('@My/Default/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

And now it can find index template at the specified route.

Answer (score -2):

Your template Path should be:

/Users/nemanja/sites/SimfoniAplikacija/app/Resources/views/index.html.twig

Regards

Comment: This is an absolute path and is ill advised.