# Unable to find template "VichUploaderBundle:form:fields.html.twig"

Tags: php, symfony, vichuploaderbundle, easyadmin

Im using Symfony 4 + Easyadmin bundle and I've got a problem, not sure if its a bug or not.

What I have done:
easy_admin.yaml

easy_admin:

```
easy_admin:
  entities:
    Category:
      class: App\Entity\Category
      list:
          fields: ["id", "name"]

      form:
        fields:
          - "name"
          - "slug"
          - "title"
          - { property: "imageFile", type: "vich_file" }
          - "description"

  design:
    form_theme:   ['VichUploaderBundle:Form:fields.html.twig', 'horizontal']
```

After I added design: form_theme etc.. I wil get this error:
"Unable to find template "VichUploaderBundle:Form:fields.html.twig" (looked into: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/paarden/templates, /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/paarden/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form)."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832977/symfony-3-4-use-view-inside-my-bundle/47835716#47835716

Comment: Its works thnx!

Comment: Nothing says thanks like an upvote.

Comment: hehe... done! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony 3.4 Use view inside my bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832977/symfony-3-4-use-view-inside-my-bundle)

Answer (score 0):

I spent more than 2 minutes to find out the solution from the linked question, so here is the answer from the comments in full:

Since Symfony 3.4/ upgrade to Symfony 4, the following change is necessary
in easy_admin.yaml:

```
design:
    form_theme:   ['VichUploaderBundle:Form:fields.html.twig', 'horizontal']
```

should be

```
design:
    form_theme:   ['@VichUploader/Form/fields.html.twig', 'horizontal']
```

The reason was pointed out in the comment by @Cerad: the twig namespaces paths were adapted to the twig convention'@BundleName/dir/twigfile.twig.