# Symfony 3.4 Extends not working after migration

Tags: php, symfony, twig, migration, symfony-3.4

I did a symfony migration from version 2.7 to version 3.4

Every thing is ok except one thing. The twig files are not working the error message is :

> Unable to find template "::layout.html.twig" (looked into: vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig/Resources/views/Form, vendor\knplabs\knp-menu\src\Knp\Menu/Resources/views) in abcdBundle::layout.html.twig at line 3.

The twig code is :

```
{% extends "::layout.html.twig" %}
```

I want to load the layout localised into `app/Resources/views/layout.thml.twig`.
I have tried this code too : `{% extends "layout.html.twig" %}` without `::` same troubles.

Location files:

```
app/
    Resources/
        views/
            layout.html.twig // it don't find this twig

src/
    ab/
        cdBundle/
            Ressources/
                views/
                    layout.html.twig // error into this file
```

Comment: Colon based template paths are no longer supported by default. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47832977/symfony-3-4-use-view-inside-my-bundle/47835716#47835716

Comment: @Cerad Ok, but how to solve my issue ? I have already seen this post. But I did not understand how to make my twig work again.

Comment: Use twig namespaces (preferred solutions) or add the twig engine to your templating config as shown at the very end of the admittedly lengthy answer.  I am assuming that this all worked under your 2.7 app and there are no typos etc.

Comment: @Cerad I have already added the templating config. All working yes before the migration. I tried this code: `{% extends "@App/layout.html.twig "%}` (with namespace), I have this error `There are no registered paths for namespace" App "`.

Comment: For 3.4 I would expect @AppBundle/layout.html.twig.  "bin/console debug:twig" will show you available namespaces.  But just plain layout.html.twig really should work.  And while I suspect it is just a question typo, Ressources is spelt wrong.  I know it can be very confusing because there are several different directory structures supported for 3.4.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks a lot, I found a solution with yours sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your project more bulletproof and ready for future migrations to Symfony 4 – consider moving all your `Resources` away from `app/` directory.

You can find more ie. in here:

http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-directory-structure.html

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the config.yml file to add :

```
twig:
    paths:
        '%kernel.project_dir%/app/Resources/views': app
```

This added the "*Namespace*" `@app` in the "*Loader Paths*" of `bin/console debug:twig`

Now, when I use `{% extends "@app/layout.html.twig" %}` its working fine.

Thank @Cerad for your help, it's very appreciated

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Just out of curiosity, does debug:twig show a "(None) namespace perhaps pointing to templates?

Comment: @Cerad Yes ! At the bottom of the list, there is a "None" pointing to `vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig/Resources/views/Form\ `. Is this the origin of the problem?

Comment: I think so.  None is the default location for templates and under the new Symfony directory structure it points to project/templates.  Don't know why it would point to a Twig bridge directory.  Might try something like '%kernel.project_dir%/templates': '' and see if you can get the need for an app namespace to go away.  It will also help if you ever upgrade to 4x.

Comment: If this path `%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/views` really exists, it's auto-added to the Twig paths (without namespace `(None)`) and so `{% extends "layout.html.twig" %}` should work.

Comment: And the Twig bridge directory is there (without namespace) because it's registered by TwigBundle to find/use/extends from any form theme layout (e.g. `form_div_layout.html.twig`) easily.

Comment: About the missing path `%kernel.project_dir%/templates/`, it is required that the directory exists to be added to the Twig paths (it apply for all paths).